# How to change cell function [not data] through drop down list

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, conditional-formatting

For my very first post I may have a slightly complex question. I've had a decent look around, and either excel doesn't have the functionality or I've got my terms mixed up.

I want to create a dynamic list (data validation drop list) that changes the function output of two cells of data into a third cell.

I've attached a screen shot with a visual representation of what I'm chasing:

Example Screen Shot:

[image]

- Cell 1 = Function selection list (Data Validation List)
- Cell 2 = Data entry
- Cell 3 = Data entry
- Cell 4 = **Outcome** of Cell 2 & Cell 3 **dependent** on function selected through Cell 1

The closet thing I've found was this:[SuperUser Question/Answer - Similar Question](https://superuser.com/questions/384535/excel-calculation-based-on-user-input-from-dropdown-fields)

I understand that there is more functionality when you add the VBscript layer to a excel spreadsheet. Though, if it can be avoided, I would prefer to accomplish this goal through standard excel functions.

Appreciate any input...

Comment: what is Cell 3 in your example? Week? Why do you use different terms in the text ("1 week", "1 Year") and in the screenshot ("weekly", "bi-monthly"...)? please edit your question to make it more understandable.

Comment: Hi Mate, after having a second look it was very convoluted.. I've made changes to the question. @MátéJuhász

Comment: Ok, it's a bit more clear now, however you still not specified, what's the frequency of the original amount.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For these specific functions you can do it easily with a support range where you store parameters for `SUBTOTAL`:

[image]

Where the formula in D1 is
`=SUBTOTAL(VLOOKUP(A1,$B$4:$C$6,2,0),B1:C1)`
`VLOOKUP`, based on value in A1 selects the correct parameter for `SUBTOTAL`